# C++ comparing integers in 2 arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

So my task is to make 3 arrays. User has to put integers in 2 of the arrays, then I must compare the integers in each position and put the higher integer in a third array, that has to be displayed on the screen.

Here is my program:

```
int main() {    
    int n; // number of elements
    cin >> n;

    int* array  = new int[n];
    int* array2 = new int[n];
    int* array3 = new int[n];

    cout << "First array: " << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    cout << "Second array:" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> array2[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array2[i]) {
            array[i] = array3[i];
            continue;
        } else if (array[i] <= array2[i]) {
            array2[i] = array3[i];
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << array3[i] << "\n ";
    }
    delete[] array;
    delete[] array2;
    delete[] array3;
}
```

So, if my first array is `1 2 3 4` and second array is `5 6 7 8` - it displays some massive negative numbers as output (`-842150421`).

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I'll suggest you to use `std::vector<int>` instead of pointers.

Comment: If `array3` is the resulting array, why do you assign integers in the third loop to `array` and `array2`? I would say you copy random integers from `array3` to the other two.

Comment: `new[]` doesn't zero-initialize elements, so you're getting junk data in the indices you don't assign manually. Try `new int[n]()`. You also never modify `array3`, I think you've got your assignments reversed.

Comment: So you're using `new[]` and `delete[]`, but not taught how to use simple functions such as `std::max`?  All of that `if` logic is one line of code using `std::max`.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing your `array3` but you haven't added any data to it, you must assign data to your array3 I suppuose that after the comparation you do between array and array2 you get the bigger data into the array3.

```
int main(){

int n; //number of elements
cin >> n;
int* array = new int[n];
int* array2 = new int[n];
int* array3 = new int[n];
cout << "First array: " << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> array[i];
cout << "Second array:" << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> array2[i];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (array[i] > array2[i]) {
        array3[i] = array[i];
        continue;
    }
    else if (array[i] <= array2[i]) {
        array3[i] = array2[i];
        continue;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << array3[i] << "\n ";
delete[] array;
delete[] array2;
delete[] array3;
}
```

I haven't modified your code but:

- I think you could remove that `continue;` as you have an else clause the code will not enter in the other condition.
- I would remove the second comparation because if it's not bigger there is the case that is equal or less so you could leave just the else without any if.

  if (array[i] > array2[i])
  {
     array3[i] = array[i];
  }
  else{
     array3[i] = array2[i];
  }

Comment: There is no need for any of that `if` logic:  `array3[i] = std::max(array1[i], array2[i]);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie true, but I understand this is a student work and the best is to keep it easy to read for him and the usual for a begginer is using if/else.

Comment: I beg to differ -- `std::max` is easier to read than `if` statements.  If you read the `std::max` statement out loud, it says what it does -- "give me the max of the two items".

Comment: Yes, but I feel this is more about how to teach and learn than how to code.

Comment: If `new[]` and `delete[]` can be used, then I don't see why also introducing the C++ library in the form of `std::max` is out-of-bounds.  Very bad teaching if this is how C++ is taught.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxima(int i , int j)
{

      if(j > i)
           return j;
   return i;
}
int main()
{
   int n; //number of elements
cin >> n;
int* array = new int[n];
int* array2 = new int[n];
int* array3 = new int[n];
cout << "First array: " << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> array[i];
cout << "Second array:" << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> array2[i];
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          array3[i] = maxima(array[i], array2[i]);
delete[] array;
delete[] array2;
delete[] array3;
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps